# how to make a programmatically generated subview conform to the bounds of the superview (iOS)?

Tags: ios, constraints, addsubview

I have a containing view called containerView which is a UIView.  When the app starts, it's just that view.  During the course of the app's execution, I want to swap two "full-size" sub views in and out of the main containerView.

My question is, how do I make sure that the sub views fill up the entire containerView regardless of the orientation of the iPad.  The containerView is 300 wide, but the height varies based on orientation.

**I've tried:**
setting the frame of the subview's from viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear directly equal to the side of the containerView frame,

creating LayoutConstraints that force the subview to conform to the containerView's proportions from viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, and viewDidAppear.  The question here is when to apply these constraints, and since the view is removed periodically, when to reapply the constraints.

I don't know what the idiomatic approach is and I want my code to be maintainable and reusable.  Am i approaching this the wrong way?  Is there some other way to make sure a subview fills up its containing view?

Example Code:
https://gist.github.com/Sahasrara/6817105

Comment: Have you used the bounds of the super view just before adding the subview and setting the constraints just after adding the subview?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  I have tried that.  For reference I'm going to try to alter the question with some example code.  I have the refresh layout at the beginning so that the bounds of the superview are correct, otherwise they are too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the frame size in viewDidLayoutSubviews.  By then all the autolayout nonsense has occurred.

Comment: So you think i should forgo using constraints programmatically and just set the frame to the superview bounds in viewDidLayoutSubviews???  It seems to be working, I just want to be sure I understand and that this is the idiomatic way of doing things.  I really striving for correctness and maintainability.

Comment: I say use constraints generally.  They work nicely.  For special case work, you need to step in and take things into your own hands.  Doing that in viewDidLayoutSubviews appears to be the best place to do that.  It is working nicely for me in several apps, one of which has hundreds of thousands of active users.
Also, we were given access to this segment of the view lifecycle in conjunction with the implementation of Autolayout.  Apparently we were given this access to do exactly the type of thing you are doing.

Comment: ok thank you so so so much for your help.  I've been struggling with this for two days now.  You've made me a happy person.